# What causes an f/0 error on a Nikon D700?

Tags: nikon, aperture, troubleshooting

Recently (and always at the worst possible time) my camera will either freeze and give me an f/0 error code or will shoot with a strange click that sounds like the shutter is getting stuck. The resulting image is always black.

My gut instinct suspects there is either a communication problem between the lens (Nikkor 24-70 ED) and the camera or the aperture diaphragm is in the process of failing.

Comment: Few links that may help.. http://www.richardpeters.co.uk/blog/2011/01/07/nikon-dslr-error-codes-what-do-they-mean/ and http://www.flickr.com/groups/nikon_d4_pros/discuss/72157629979017913/

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=nikon+d700+f0+error

Comment: Sending camera and lens in for repair and maintenance. Will report back when I know what's going on award points if valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar error of "f/0" after putting my 55-300mm lens on my D7000.

I examines the small connecting needles at the rear end of the lens. The number of these needle heads varies depending on the type of lens — a 55-300 has 8 needle heads; a 18-200mm has 10. These serve as connectors from the lens to the camera body. They spring up and down upon installation/uninstallation of the lens to the body. In time, they accumulate dust and do not spring back up. Upon examination of my lens, I found that one of the needles did not spring up when I changed my lens.

I took a household needle and carefully and gently picked up on the sunken needle head while using a hand-air-blower to clean away the accumulated dust. After some patience, the needle head popped again to its normal position, as with the other needles beside it — and the f/0 error is gone and I was able to use my lens again. Please remember to cover the exposed glass at the rear end of the lens while pumping the air blower, so that dust won't move in your lens.

I hope this DIY experience will help. If it fails, I suggest you send your lens to the service center.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible reason

1. your lens is not chipped, thus the camera is unable to detect what kind of lens you are doing. To solve this go to setup menu ->non-cpu lens data and setup a lens. (refer to page 211 of your manual)
2. You lens have a aperture ring and its not locked to allow the camera to control the aperture of the lens. I am not sure how this is done on a Sigma, for Nikon this is usually done by setting the lens to f-22

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I get that error almost always when my lens doesn't sit properly.  if your lens has an aperture ring and a manual minimum aperture lock lever, try locking it to a higher number and working your way to a lower number(bigger aperture) until the error doesn't show.

Comment: "I get that error almost always when my lens doesn't sit properly." Same here.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that some dirt has gotten into your lens and the aperture blades are getting jammed. I had a similar issue a few months back and sent my lens for repair.